# Performance de app nativo ainda é muito superior a app baseado em html?

Tags: mobile, ionic, desempenho, xamarin

Estou em dúvida sobre qual framework/linguagem utilizar para iniciar desenvolvimento de aplicativos.
Pelo que li até agora, estou entre usar [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com) e [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com).

Em todo lugar que leio a grande vantagem do Ionic é ser gratuito, mas agora o Xamarin também é gratuito, então nisso eles estão iguais.
Outra questão que enfatizam bastante é que app nativo tem melhor performance do que app baseado em html, mas igual a questão do Xamarin ser pago, pode ser que isso já mudou hoje em dia. Sobre interface vi que agora partes do CSS3 são [aceleradas pela GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148012/what-exact-parts-of-css3-are-gpu-accelerated).

- A performance geral de apps nativos continua sendo melhor?
- A interface de apps nativos ainda é perceptivelmente mais responsiva?
- A performance de algum desses tipos de apps é mais influenciada por tamanho ou complexidade do projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Performance**

Eu recomendo utilizar a própria [IDE do Google](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/sdk/index.html) para desenvolvimento de APPs para android, o desempenho de uma APP nativa sempre será superior. Uma IDE dessas trabalha geralmente com compilação e o resultado final "é o mesmo" de um APP nativo com alguns processos a mais, ou seja, desempenho menor.

**Responsivo**

Depende do seu projeto, no geral o resultado é o mesmo, porem ainda sim um app nativo lida mais facilmente com mudanças de resolução.

**Performance por tamanho/complexidade**

Depende da forma que o Ionic por exemplo compila o app, obviamente não ficará menor que um APP nativo pois deve importar parte da core do programa para o aplicativo, consequentemente fica maior ou mais "pesado" de rodar.

**Considerações Gerais**

Você terá algumas limitações técnicas por depender de aplicativos de terceiros (sem ser original) para desenvolver já que você não pode ter 100% de liberdade em um aparelho mobile usando somente HTML, JavaScript e CSS3.

Comment: Realmente o melhor é fazer apps nativos, mas é inviável para uma equipe pequena fazer e manter 3 aplicativos diferentes. Por isso estou querendo saber justamente as diferenças de Ionic e Xamarin.